my wordpress menu shows all pages on the wordpress
I made some changes about their location on the menu. Then my menu shows all pages. you can see the detail in the photos.
my menu on site

my menu on the wp

ı read forums that closed to my problem but nothing is changed.sorry for bad language
-Edit 1 :I am preparing wordpress menu titles,locations etc.. I'm saving. but there is no change on my website. Whenever I create a new page in WordPress, it throws the page name directly into the menu. I can not adjust menu on wordpress
I have read some article about issue, they said that when there is no primary menu wordpress shows all pages. but i clicked primary menu.

what is the actual issue? can you please explain? like you want the sub-menu? or there is something else? Also when you change the menu then you have double check the menu name? like which menu you change and which one is showing?

I am preparing wordpress menu titles,locations etc.. I'm saving. but there is no change on my website. Whenever I create a new page in WordPress, it throws the page name directly into the menu. I can not adjust menu on wordpress.

I have read some article about issue, they said that when there is no primary menu wordpress shows all pages. but i clicked primary menu.

check the setting in Menu Tab, and make sure you have assign all the links/pages to the menu which you are using as primary menu. Also check your website in Incognito Mode
